# Add an array to a associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add an array to an associative array.

```
$contents = glob(DIR_IMAGE."catalog/Data_PDF/*");

$contents_pregged['name'] = preg_replace("(".DIR_IMAGE.")", "", $contents); 
$contents_pregged['link'] = preg_replace("(catalog/Data_PDF/)", "", $contents_pregged['name']); 

$data['contents'][] = array(
    'name' => $contents_pregged['name'],
    'link' => $contents_pregged['link']
);
```

The above example is within the controller and if i send the data alone it echos out all the files listed but i would like to use the arrays in an associative array so i can echo out the name and links using the example below.

```
{% for content in contents %} 
      <li><a href = "/image/{{content.link}}">{{content.name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The responsive i get on the front end is Array

I have at the moment 3 files in the directory so the array should return 3 values

Comment: `$data['contents'] = array(` remove the []

Comment: Returns no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob()` returns an array.

It will be easier if you would first iterate over the files you get from `glob()`. And you don't really need regular expressions to extract the file name parts:

```
foreach($contents as $file) {
    $data['contents'][] = [
        "name" => str_replace(DIR_IMAGE, "", $file),
        "link" => basename($file)
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because both `$contents_pregged['name']` and `$contents_pregged['link']` are **arrays**, because `$contents` is array also.

So you need somehow iterate over your `$contents_pregged` so as in `$data['contents']` you will have data which you need. A simple solution can be:

```
foreach ($contents_pregged['name'] as $k => $v) {
    $data['contents'][] = array(
        'name' => $v,
        // here we get value of `$contents_pregged['link']` with same key
        'link' => $contents_pregged['link'][$k],
    );
}
```

After that you can iterate over `$contents` in a template as you want.